# Cadastrar usuário com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

estou montando uma aplicação, onde é feito cadastro de um funcionário, e este funcionário pertence à uma empresa, que vem da tabela users.

Quando faço o processo de cadastro, aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'users_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `funcionarios` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `perfil_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Gustavo, gtbarbosa@live.com, $2y$10$nRqXsSPGybF1rMFQRsMwLOmiofkGp7voaJRnOwUEewMYXR1oyBDya, 3, 2018-07-03 01:36:22, 2018-07-03 01:36:22)) ◀"
```

Porém, analisando o código, e debugando ele, a variável que passa o id para a tabela funcionarios vem preenchida com o id do usuário logado. O método está da seguinte forma:

```
public function cadastraFuncionario(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => ['required', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'max:255', 'email', 'unique:funcionarios'],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:6', 'max:20']
        ]);

        $id_empresa = Auth::user()->id;

        $credentials = array_merge($request->all(), [
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'perfil_id' => 3,
            'users_id' => $id_empresa,
        ]);

        var_dump($credentials);

        Funcionario::create($credentials);

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

Quando dou um var_dump na variável, tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
C:\Users\Gustavo\project-manager\app\Http\Controllers\FuncionarioController.php:34:
array (size=6)
  '_token' => string 'xAhxSeW6hQVb1k5PFYhgTvd8Y7rWkmn38IXt08ND' (length=40)
  'name' => string 'Gustavo' (length=7)
  'email' => string 'my@mail.com' (length=18)
  'password' => string '$2y$10$hS816jGMo2BHpgL8/7d/buWmrwnKKjjiW.dIxYwnEFaMMwyAgZClS' (length=60)
  'perfil_id' => int 3
  'users_id' => int 1
```

Não consigo identificar o erro. Inclusive já tentei setar o valor direto no corpo do método, assim como fiz com o perfil_id, mas não funciona.

Comment: Por favor, adicione seu Model Funcionario no exemplo para facilitar o entendimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema do seu código está na utilização do `Funcionario::create`. Esse método usa [Mass Assingment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment) que "bloqueia" os campos e só permitem a inserção dos campos que estão especificados no `$fillable` da model. Para solucionar o seu problema, faça atribuição dos valores do seu request para um objeto Funcionário e utilize o método save.

```
public function cadastraFuncionario(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => ['required', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'max:255', 'email', 'unique:funcionarios'],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:6', 'max:20']
        ]);

        $id_empresa = Auth::user()->id;

        $funcionario = new Funcionario;
        $funcionario->name = $request->name;
        $funcionario->email = $request->email;
        $funcionario->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $funcionario->perfil_id = 3;
        $funcionario->users_id = $id_empresa;

        $funcionario->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua resposta, talvez por falta de conhecimento, ainda sou iniciante no Laravel. Mas pelo que entendi, usando Funcionario::create, no model $fillable deve estar especificado 'users_id', certo? Se for isto, já especifiquei. Agora sobre sua solução, como faço atribuição dos valores para o objeto?

Comment: Alterei a resposta para você ver como é feito.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema recente em relação a esse erro onde tanto a Model, Controller e Migrations estavam ok. Após as tentativas sem sucesso, resolvi analisar o código novamente. Percebi que no formulário de cadastro eu não havia dado às inputs um name. Após inseri-los, o problema foi resolvido.

Ex: < input name="title_intro" type="text" placeholder="insira o titulo">

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde, neste caso não seria perfil_id no lugar de User_id?

Nos detalhes me aparenta que voce está passando o valor nulo em user_id:

'Campo users_id nao possui um valor padrao'
Field 'users_id' doesn't have a default value

Voce possui este campo users_id na sua tabela de funcionários?

Comment: a parte de resposta devem ser objetivas e que buscam solucionar a pergunta feita. Esses questionamentos que você fez devem ser feitas na área de comentário que você terá privilégio quando chegar a reputação 50. Acesse a central de ajuda para mais informações.

Comment: Obrigado @FelipeJ.R.Vieira